# Unexpected unindent error Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, indentation

This was bugging me for quite a while and I finally decided to post this for help. I need an answer as soon as possible.

```
def _define_username() -> str:
''' Asks for username'''
while True:
    username = input('Login: ').strip()
    if len(username) > 1:
        return username
    else:
        print( 'Sorry, ' + username + ' is not a valid host')
```

Comment: I'm getting an `IndentationError: expected an indented block` pointing to line 2, which should alert you of the problem @datguy answers below.

Comment: Ensure you do not use tabs in your editor! Python uses indentation to identify blocks of code (conditionals, loops, functions, classes). Depending on user settings the tabs can expand to 1, 2, 4, or any number of characters. The combination of tabs with a syntax that depends on indentation levels will cause havoc. All current editors can be set in a mode where they enforce replacement of tabs with a given number of spaces. Ensure this is in use. Then visualize all tabs in your code still existing from previous editing, and replace them with spaces. Again, most editors can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Python is picky about indentation.  Try indenting the function's body:

```
def _define_username() -> str:
    ''' Asks for username'''
    while True:
        username = input('Login: ').strip()
        if len(username) > 1:
            return username
        else:
            print( 'Sorry, ' + username + ' is not a valid host')
```

Comment: you need to indent the line underneath `while True:`

Comment: That's because you also need to indent the docstring (`''' Asks for username '''`)

Comment: The above code works as expected in `Python 3.3.1`, fixing the indentation problem that the question's code has.

Comment: is this the only code in the program? maybe it has wrong indentation with the rest of the code.